# How to update layout with a dropdown in PySimpleGUI? (Python)

Tags: python, pysimplegui

This is what I have going so far:

```py
from PySimpleGUI import *

language = [
    ["English"],
    ["Portuguese"]
]

layout = [
    [InputOptionMenu(language, key="inp")],
    [Text("HI THIS IS ENGLISH", key="txt")]
]

window = Window("test", layout)

while True:
    event, value = window.read()
    if event == None or event == "Exit":
        break
    
    # this may be the issue:

    if value["inp"] == "English":
        pass
    elif value["inp"] == "Portuguese":
        pt = "OI ESSE E PORTUGUES"
        window.FindElement("txt").Update(pt)
    else:
        event = None
```

I was expecting the text to change when selecting Portuguese in the dropdown but nothing happens.

Comment: Did you try to check what `value["inp"]` is equal to when the event is received, for examle by using `print`?

Answer (score 0):

Something wrong here

- The value for OptionMenu should be `["English", "Portuguese"]`.
- There's no event generated for the `OptionMenu` element at this moment.

Add tkinter code to generate event when the value of `OptionMenu` element updated.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def callback(var, index, mode):
    """
    For OptionMenu
    var - tkinter control variable.
    index - index of var, '' if var is not a list.
    mode - 'w' for 'write' here.
    """
    window.write_event_value("Language", window['-IN-'].TKStringVar.get())

languages = ["English", "Portuguese"]
layout = [
    [sg.OptionMenu(languages, expand_x=True, key="-IN-")],
    [sg.Text("HI THIS IS ENGLISH", size=20, key="-OUT-")],
    [sg.Push(), sg.Button('Exit')],
]
window = sg.Window("Title", layout, finalize=True)
window['-IN-'].TKStringVar.trace("w", callback)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event in (sg.WIN_CLOSED, 'Exit'):
        break
    elif event == 'Language':
        language = values[event]
        window['-OUT-'].update(f"HI THIS IS {language}")

window.close()
```

[image]

Comment: error 1: `TypeError: OptionMenu.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'expand_x'`



 ....  i removed `expand_x=True`



error 2: `AttributeError: module 'PySimpleGUI' has no attribute 'Push'`



... i removed `sg.Push()`



error 3: `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object`



... i removed `size=20`



ok, the gui finally appears but when i change the language...



error 4: `AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'write_event_value'`

Comment: It looks like that the version of your PySimpleGUi is very old, update it to latest version.